# How to implement real time data editing in tables using angular 6

Tags: angular

I am developing a mean stack application in which I want to implement real time data editing on my component. I have my API working fine using patch where I just edit the first name and using the matdialog but unfortunately my data doesn't change after i click update what am I missing here guys thank you so much if I find my help tonight.

**user.service.ts**:

```
import {Injectabl} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {User} from '../model/User.model'
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {from,Observable,Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

    users: User[];
    updateUsers = new Subject < User[] > ();
    selectedUser: User;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getAdmins() {
        return this.http.get(environment.api_url + 'admins')
    }

    //fetch students from api
    getAllstudents() {
        return this.http.get(environment.api_url + 'admins')
    }

    //update user info
    UpdateuserInfo(admin: User) {
        return this.http.patch(environment.api_url + `/${admin.firstname}`, admin);
    }

}
```

**editstudentindebt.component.ts**:

```
import {Component,OnInit,Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatDialog,MatDialogRef,MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';
import {User} from '../model/User.model'
import {DialogeditComponent} from '../dialogedit/dialogedit.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-editstudentindebt',
    templateUrl: './editstudentindebt.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./editstudentindebt.component.css']
})
export class EditstudentindebtComponent implements OnInit {

    displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'regno', 'amount', 'reason', 'action'];
    dataSource;
    user;
    users: User[];

    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private userservice: UserService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userservice.getAdmins()
            .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
                this.users = users;
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);

            });
    }

    editUser(user: User) {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogeditComponent, {
            width: '250px',
            data: user

        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            this.user = user;
        });
    }
}
```

**editstudentinddebt.html**:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search Students">
            </mat-form-field>

            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                <!-- Position Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
                    <th style="text-align: center;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
                    <td style="text-align: center;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Name Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
                    <th style="text-align: center;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </th>
                    <td style="text-align: center;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstname}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Weight Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
                    <th style="text-align: center;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </th>
                    <td style="text-align: center;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastname}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Symbol Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="regno">
                    <th style="text-align: center;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Registration Number </th>
                    <td style="text-align: center;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.regno}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <!-- Symbol Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
                    <th style="text-align: center;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Amount </th>
                    <td style="text-align: center;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.amount}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <!-- Symbol Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="reason">
                    <th style="text-align: center;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Reason</th>
                    <td style="text-align: center;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.reason}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
                        <button style="align-self: auto;" mat-raised-button class="homeButtons" type="button"
                            (click)="editUser(user)"> <i class="material-icons">edit</i></button>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**dialogedit.component.ts**:

```
import {Component,OnInit,Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog,MatDialogRef,MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {User} from '../model/User.model';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dialogedit',
    templateUrl: './dialogedit.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dialogedit.component.css'],
    providers: [UserService]
})
export class DialogeditComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef < DialogeditComponent > ,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: User, private uservice: UserService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    OnEdit(admin: User) {
        this.uservice.selectedUser = admin;
    }

}
```

**dialogedit.component.html**:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.firstname" placeholder="Amount">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.reason" placeholder="Reason">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close] (click)="OnEdit(admin)" cdkFocusInitial>Update</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks bro would you help me with this one

Comment: You have provided a lot of code. Can you isolate the piece where the problem lies or reproduce the issue in a demo?

Comment: i actually am getting firstname of undefined on my uservice.ts

Comment: Which means you are not getting value in **admin** variable. Just do a console log and see what you are getting in the service function. If it is undefined, make sure you are passing proper value while calling that function.

Comment: Where are you calling `UpdateuserInfo` and what is `admin` in your template `(click)="OnEdit(admin)"`

Comment: @VikramSingh its on the userservice inside the OnEdit Function

Comment: `OnEdit` function is in your component and you are nowhere calling `UpdateuserInfo` method. and also you are passing undefined in `OnEdit` function in your template. Because i am not able to see any variable named admin in your component.

Comment: okay bro so what should i implement @VikramSingh

Comment: but i have claeed it in my DialogEdit component @VikramSingh

Comment: Please give a minimal reproducible example -https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example